# Git status content is different in different linux account

Tags: linux, git-pull

There are two accounts in linux server, root and super.

I can git pull to latest code by root account

I cannot git pull to latest code by super account

I found the status content is different by execute git status

```
super@api-dev:~/dnmp/www/localhost$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../../data/
        ../../docker-compose.yml
        ../../services/
        ../

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

...

root@api-dev:~/dnmp/www/localhost# git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   composer.lock

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

There is a git repository root in ~/dnmp/

There is another git repository root in ~/dnmp/www/localhost

I want to change git status of super account to the same as root content.

Any idea to fix the difference?

Answer (score 0):

`git` is different from other source control systems.  When you clone a repository, it creates a local repository copy on your computer.  So you have 1 copy as root, and another copy as super.

Then you can modify the files in your local copy, even commit these changes.  But the main repository will not know of these until you push them into it.

So, when you run `git status` it shows you the state of the **local** repository, **not** the state of the main git repository.

To sync your local repositories with the main one, you can:

- delete your local repository and clone from scratch.
- pull the files from the main repository with `git pull`.
- If you want to keep some changes you made locally, you will have to commit and push these up to the main repository first.

You can read on `git`, like this simple page: https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

More in depth sites exist to explain the whole of git, like:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-git-and-how-to-use-it-c341b049ae61/